# Treat multiple adjacent <li> items as one single item without wrapping them in another element

Tags: css

I have an `<ul>` that I have no control over (react),a nd I want to put a box and border around some of them.

Basically, I have:

```
<ul>
  <li>Results...</li>
  <li><</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>></li>
  <li>Something else</li>
</ul>
```

Screenshot: [image]

And I want them to be wrapped like this:

[image]

The problem like I said is that I dont have control over the actual element and the way it is being rendered, so I can't redo it with `div`s, and I want to wrap all `li` items except the first and last.

Current HTML is, the way the component renders it is :

```
<ul class="ant-pagination">
  <li class="ant-pagination-total-text">Results...</li>
  <li class="ant-pagination-prev"><</li>
  <li class="ant-pagination-item">1</li>
  <li class="ant-pagination-item">2</li>
  <li class="ant-pagination-next">></li>
  <li class="ant-pagination-options">Dropdown with options about setting table page size</li>
</ul>
```

The CSS that I have applied to reorder the items the way I need them displayed:

```
.ant-pagination {
  justify-content: center;
} 

.ant-pagination > li:last-child {
  order: 1;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.ant-pagination > li:first-child {
  order: 2;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.ant-pagination > li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
  order: 3;
}
```

This CSS reordered the items the way I need them to be:

[image]

Of course I have additional styling CSS on top of that.

`.ant-pagination > li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)` this selector targets the items that I need to be targeted and want wrapped.

In essence I need to do:

```
<ul>
  <li>Results...</li>
  <div class="li-wrapper">
    <li><</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>></li>
  </div>
  <li>Something else</li>
</ul>

.li-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: What's the existing CSS and HTML that you're working with, relevant to this specific component?

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica I have added more info to the post. Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to use JavaScript to modify the component, because while a border can be faked it would be easier - and arguably more semantically-correct - to group the page numbers in a descendant `<ol>`.

Comment: @Rob I never said it is, I was just trying to illustrate what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul li {
  padding: 4px;
  max-width: 16px;
}

ul li:not(:first-child, :last-child) { 
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

ul li:nth-last-child(2) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

ul li:nth-child(2) {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
</ul>
```

May be using the :not selector of CSS, like:

```
ul li:not(:first-child, :last-child) { 
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: I can target them, I can't put a wrapper around all of them, that is what I am trying to do. A border around ALL of them treated as a single element.

Comment: Maybe you want it to be like this? I've just updated the snippet above, you may try it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not understanding it well but I am not sure what you meant by you have no control over the elements but then you applied CSS to those elements. Anyway, wouldn't a simple border style and padding in your `ant-pagination` work?

```
.ant-pagination {
  background: 1px solid black;
  //or whatever padding the design says
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: .ant-pagination is the hole <ul> list, I want to apply the border only around the items in the middle of the list without first and last child, and since they are not right next to each other, they also have border radius and so on, they need to be wrapped somehow into another component